# aframe How can I trigger a function when my cursor mouseenter or click an entity

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I am using aframe and have the jquery library. I seek to trigger a function call when the cursor hovers over an entity. In this case the entity is an a-video tag.

Here is my cursor:

```
<a-entity camera look-controls>
  <a-cursor id="cursor" animation__click="property: scale; startEvents: click; from: 0.1 0.1 0.1; to: 1 1 1; dur: 150" animation__fusing="property: fusing; startEvents: fusing; from: 1 1 1; to: 0.1 0.1 0.1; dur: 1500" event-set__1="_event: mouseenter; color: #f89828;" event-set__2="_event: mouseleave; color: black" fuse="true" raycaster="objects: .link"></a-cursor>
</a-entity>
```

Here is my a-video

```
 <a-assets><video id="ceo-video" loop preload="auto" webkit-playsinline src="./values.mp4"></a-assets>
    <a-video cursor-listener="on: click;" id="a-video" src="#ceo-video" data-video-source="ceo-video" position="-9 0.953 -0.999" class="alan-video" width="5" height="3" rotation="0 90 0">
    </a-video>
```

This is my AFRAME component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('cursor-listener', {
  schema: {
    on: { type: 'string' },
    target: { type: 'selector' },
    src: { type: 'string' },
    dur: { type: 'number', default: 300 }
  },

  init: function() {
    var vid = document.getElementById('ceo-video');
    this.el.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
      vid.play();
    });
    this.el.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
      vid.pause();
    });
  }
});
```

The click or mouseenter events are never being triggered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You listen for the click event twice, playing and pausing the video.

You need to have ONE listener and a boolean switch inside checking whether to play or pause the video like this:

```
var switch
if(switch){
  playVideo();
  switch!=switch;
}else{
  pauseVideo();
  switch!=switch;
}
```

If You want to listen for the mouseEnter event, You need to make another event listener:

```
this.el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(evt) {
  vid.play();
});
```

If You're using [ngoKevin's event component](https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-event-set-component), just replace `_event: click` with `_event: mouseenter`